# remove bone weight from the mirrored side of mesh

Tags: rigging

[image: double weighted]

[image: no weights]

is it possible to erase the weight on the R side and then redo the weight mirroring?

selected bone (thumb_upper_L) used to have wrong name (without the "_L" suffix), the mesh has Mirror modifier on it. also, some parts are manually re-weighted, so un-parenting isn't an option unless there's a way to preserve repainted weights.

i've tried applying Mirror modifier, deleting and renaming bones and painting on applied topology in different order multiple times, but i only managed to propagate the problem to the rest of thumb bones.

Comment: found a way to redo the weight painting for both bones, but that means potentially changing topology around the vertices being repainted:

1. apply Mirror modifier;

2. apply Automatic Weights to both bones;

3. delete the right part of the mesh;

4. add Mirror modifier;

5. left and right bones are mirrored now, left bone weights can be repainted normally to affect right bone in the exact same way, as it should be.

Still looking for the "perfect" way of doing this without ruining already existing work

Comment: There is a method using "Copy Vertex Group" and "Mirror Vertex Group".